# Use tf.shape(tf.where(condition)) as a bound for a loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensor

I want to use the shape (size) of a tf.where for the bound of a for-loop using Tensorflow in Pycharm. However, when I try to do this, I get the error: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

How can I solve this problem?

**Development contents.

1. Find the index (idxCut) corresponding to the threshold in the data.

2. Check whether data corresponding to idxCut is TPR.**

I want to find the TPR (Turning Point Ratio) about idxCut in the data using a for-loop.
I used a for-loop to obtain the TPR between idx, idx-1 and idx + 1.
I want to find data[idx] is higher than the others data[idx-1, idx+1].

Here's my code:

```
def funCalculate(data):
    ### Cut-off Threshold
    idxCut = tf.where(data > cutoff)
    idxCut = tf.squeeze(idxCut)

    ### Compute by the size of idxCut
    valueCut = []
    for ii in range(0, tf.shape(idxCut)):
        v1 = tf.where(data[idxCut[ii]] > data[idxCut[ii] - 1], 1, 0)
        v2 = tf.where(data[idxCut[ii]] > data[idxCut[ii] + 1], 1, 0)
        v3 = tf.where(v1 + v2 > 1, 1, 0)
        valueCut.append(v3)
    return valueCut
```

Comment: `tf.shape` returns a tensor not an int see https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape

Comment: look like completely wrong try of doing something what shoulod be done otherway without a loop. Why loop over shape? what do you do there?

Comment: I want to find the TPR about idxCut in the data using a for-loop. I used a for-loop to obtain the TPR between idx, idx-1 and idx + 1.